# Continuous Integration Workflow with Jenkins, Gerrit, and Submodules

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules, gerrit

Suppose that we have a C++ project which consists of a library and an executable. I'd like to keep each in its own git repository so the library can be used by other projects. I've been researching a reasonable workflow for using gerrit with git submodules.

I read about [gerrit's ability to have a superproject subscribe to changes in a submodule](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-submodules.html), so I was planning to use this feature to automatically have the master branch in the superproject include the latest submitted changes in the master branch in the submodule. This provides history of which submodule commit is associated with a superproject commit, which is the reason why I'm considering submodules instead of repo.

Once the superproject is subscribed to changes in the submodule, it seems like the best workflow would be to never have developers update the submodule reference in changes pushed to gerrit, and instead rely on the subscription to update the submodule reference in the superproject. But, this means that continuous integration pre-commit testing has no idea the submodule change is required, so any change with a dependency on the submodule can't be verified until the change in the submodule is submitted.

If developers do update the submodule reference in their superproject changes, continuous integration works fine but there are other problems:

1. I have gerrit configured to use a [submit type](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-configuration.html#submit_type) of `Cherry-pick` because I like to have the `Reviewed-on:` links back to the changes on gerrit in the commit messages. This allows us to do some postmortem bug analysis by looking at each patch set on a gerrit change. But, this creates a different commit when submitting, so the commit specified in the submodule reference of the superproject's change is only a patch set, not the submitted change.
2. It becomes difficult to handle merge conflicts if multiple changes which have a submodule dependency are under review at the same time, since only the first change can be submitted and subsequent changes will get a merge conflict because the submodule base has changed.

Does anyone have a suggestion to improve this workflow by eliminating some of the pain points above?

Comment: Can the developers wait for submodule change be submitted before they change the superproject if the change has submodule dependency?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira, in some cases it is not possible to wait. For example, I may have a case where I need to change the subproject and superproject at the same time to avoid breaking the baseline in the superproject. For example, if I need to make a change to the interface between the superproject and submodule the changes need to be submitted together.

Comment: +1. I am struggling with the same issue. It seems that Gerrit or any other multi-project pre-submit CI setup will have this issue. BitBucket appears to solve this with a same-named branches, but this forces you to do exaclty 1 pull request per repo per issue. Also not so elegant. In Gerrit you could use Topics and enforce to submit them together, but as you indicate, CI does not know what to check out to verify. P.S. You may want to use 'Rebase Always' submit type, which has the same benefits of 'Cherry Pick', but works with dependent changes, ie. solving your second point.